# Delphi 7 - Prevent User From Killing Process in Task Manager

Tags: windows, delphi, process, taskmanager

This code bellow can prevent application to be killed throught Windows Task Manager:

```
SetSecurityInfo(OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, GetCurrentProcessID),
  SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, @ACL, nil);
```

The problem it works only on Windows 7. So, I have two questions:

- Do you know how to adapt this code (or another approach) that works also on XP and 8 ?
- How can I allow users to kill the process after preventing them from doing so once? I'd like to include an option (checkbox) like this: "Prevent users from killing application" that can be checked or not.

By the way, I am not creating any kind of virus, malware, spyware, etc.

Comment: Use a service for this. If users insist on killing a service on their heads be it. A third party program/service that cannot be killed is malware.

Comment: Some services use a "guardian" approach for this - a pair of services monitor each other and will restart each other if either is improperly terminated.

Comment: @David, my application is digitally signed, so it doesn´t have problems with antivirus tools. By the way, I do not think a "normal" application, with windows (forms) can be used as a service... Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @J..., It is an idea to solve the problem, but for now I am looking for an easier way (if there is one :))

Comment: @Paruba Signed or otherwise, it is malware if it cannot be terminated. I'm not talking about what an AV tool will think when it encounters your app, but I'm categorising something that cannot be killed as malware. And as for what the AV tools will think, the easier solution you are looking for will make your app look even more like malware to the AV tools.

Comment: As written, you are trying to solve the wrong problem.  The question is not how do you stop them from shutting your software down - the question is WHY are they shutting your software down - fix that problem instead (which may not be a software fix).

Comment: @Xepol, you are right. Maybe I suggest the manager to hire a psychologist to try to understand why some employees just stop their work to &#ck with mine... :) Maybe do a group therapy... I should participate, by the way ... :)

Comment: @Paruba: No, perhaps you should talk to those users and find out why your software is doing something they dislike so much they feel the need to stop it, and then fix your software so it's not doing that any longer. Most users who stop software that they're not actively using are doing so because it's causing them a problem or is behaving badly.

Comment: @KenWhite, I think they are doing this just for "fun"... or maybe because they are unhappy with their jobs / bosses... This problem happens once a while, but my job is to avoit it to happen... Thanks!

Comment: @Paruba: I highly doubt it. "My boss told me to leave this software running, but for fun I'm going to defy them and stop it anyway." sounds pretty foolish, and could possibly end up with loss of their job. There is an annoyance factor, and the proper solution is to find out what that annoying behavior is and see if you can address it instead, rather than trying to force them to keep being annoyed. As I said, there is a *reason* (other than to irritate you) that they're closing down your app. If you choose to ignore that fact, good luck. You're starting down a long path; angry users are no fun.

Comment: The likely reason is that your app brings the users' computers to a grinding halt. Fix that, problem over.

Comment: @KenWhite, do not judge by experiences in your own country / culture. Unfortunatelly (for me), here in Brazil people are different from your country...  Well, I will try the "service" approach for the solution ... Thank you anyway...

Comment: If your app made my computer slow, then I'd kill it in a heartbeat, and I am not Brazilian.

Comment: @Paruba Well, I am Brazilian and my customers do not kill my apps. It doesn't make sense at all. Perhaps your app is doing something harmfull. Why a customer would kill an usefull application? Why he/she would have to use Task Manager for that?

Comment: If you insist on this subject. This [question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/30985) probably will help you

Comment: The question was misunderstood, so I edited it. The point isn´t why application is being killed, but how to solve it "programmatically". Thanks!

Comment: @Paruba I agree with David Heffernan, your app likely getting forced down because it is, in some way, causing problems.  However, you may find that the problem is a lack of user training.

Your attitude, however, is clearly a problem here - you need to work WITH your operators, not against them.  So yes, TALK to them, find out why they are shutting down your software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it.

See the canonical answer on security StackExchange:

- [Create a unterminable process in Windows](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31006/3874)

Short version:

1. Pre-NT **RegisterServiceProcess** trick - marks your process as a *"critical system service"*
2. Process naming tricks - TaskMgr refused to kill processes named `rpcss.exe`
3. Keep-alive processes - two processes keep relaunching each other
4. User-mode hook **TerminateProcess** via loaded DLLs - block calls to terminate your process
5. User-mode hook TerminateProcess via injected threads - block calls to terminate your process
6. Kernel-mode call hooks - takeover any calls to TerminateProcess inside the kernel from a driver
7. Direct kernel object manipulation (DKOM) - modify the kernel process list so your process is invisible
8. Debugger tricks - if you debug your own process it cannot be killed
9. **Windows [Protected Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-)** - the OS feature to make a process unkillable
10. Tool manipulation - modify TaskMgr, Process Explorer, pskill, taskkill binaries directly

Yes, anti-virus, anti-malware, and DRM software should not be able to defend itself from malware that gains administrative privileges. But Microsoft, McAfee, Cylance, WildVine, and the rest do it - and Microsoft endorses and enabled with with protected services. So here we are.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, for a very good reason: even though you aren't creating malware, *if it were possible for you it would also be possible for malware authors.*

Also, when all is said and done, *the owner of the computer owns the computer,* and has final say in how it runs.  [This is a deliberate design decision in Windows,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx) according to Raymond Chen, one of the major developers on the Windows team.  If your software tries to take that basic right away, then the owner of the computer will regard your software as malware, whether you intend it to be or not.

You really should listen to the people posting comments.  People don't do things without a reason.  If your users are killing the process, the problem isn't "the process can be killed when it shouldn't be"; the problem is "your process is doing something that makes people want to kill it."  You have a social problem, not a technological one, and experience has shown that trying to solve a social problem by technical means *always* makes things worse.

Try talking to your users and figuring out what's going on that's making them want to kill your process so much, and see if you can fix whatever it is and improve their experience.  But don't try to make the process unkillable.  That's an arms race you don't want to get into, because in the end you'll always lose.

Comment: I know many softwares, like antivirus and security applications, that prevent it process to be killed. You need to understand that company manager asked me to add this functionality, with owner agreement. The computers belong to company, not employs (users). Anyway, I am tired arguing with you... have a nice day!

Comment: can you remove the right of them to access Task Manager in windows, this would solve your issue with no need to use code, i assume it can be done using windows user rights stuff?

Comment: @Shaun I can kill processes without using task manager. Also, task manager has other uses.

Comment: @Paruba I can disable my AV software.

Comment: @David to be honest if you determined to kill an application you can find a way. i you were to create a service you can set it to restart on failures.

Comment: @paruba  You are getting good advice from people here.  Ignore it at your peril, because eventually managers are going to start asking what the point of software is if people keep disabling it.   Find the root cause, fix that.  Or your manager will.

Comment: @Shaun07776, thank you for the tip! I will block Windows Task Manager, and this should be enough...

Comment: It's also possible we've trying to answer a question by reading the other side of a contract. Nearly all anti-virus applications, including those from Microsoft, deliberately make their processes unkillable. We know how to alter the ACLs on a **service** to grant **Administrators** permission to stop a service. But we have no idea how AV software is able [to mark its process to be unkillable](https://superuser.com/questions/109010/kill-a-process-which-says-access-denied). It's possible they're applying an ACL to the process object; but nobody knows what permission is being denied. So we ask.